# change only a border color in UIPopoverController using custom UIPopoverBackgroundView

Tags: ios, uipopover, uipopoverbackgroundview

I know that there are several similar questions and there are several tutorials on this subject(like this one : http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/customizing-the-design-of-uipopovercontroller). But my need is just to change a popover border color, and it seems like it's not possible to do it without changes of the other popover components. Creating a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView there are several required methods to override. Is it just a popover component architecture problem or I've missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you haven't missed anything, Its the problem of component architecture problem as far as I know.

For customising the popover border you have to follow the same way as described in the tutorial you have mentioned.